# What is the IP range of Sitecore Email Cloud (port 587)

Tags: exm

We are setting up a new production environment which utilizes the new Sitecore Email Cloud (Sparkpost and EXM 3.4). Our hosting vendor does not allow us to open for all traffic on port 587, so we need a hostname and/or an IP range to open. I have crawled the document but have only found this statement in [doc.sitecore.net](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/message_transfer_agent/set_up_the_message_transfer_agent_mta):

- Make sure the firewall on your server does not block the following
  URL's:

  - https://apps.sitecore.net
  - smtp.sitecore.sparkpostelite.com
  - https://sparkpost.cloud.sitecore.net
  - https://sitecore.sparkpostelite.com/
- Open port 587 to support the
  Transport Layer Security (TLS). TLS is required by Sitecore MTA to
  send email messages.

From the above it seems that I need to open up for all traffic to port 587, not only for the specific 4 URLs.

Comment: please write to sitecore support about sparkpost smtp ip

Comment: port 587 will only apply to the `smtp.sitecore.sparkpostelite.com` machine; https is port 443.

Comment: @RichardHauer: I just received the same response from Sitecore support. Could you create a response to this question, so that i can mark it as resolved?

Comment: See https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/message_transfer_agent/set_up_the_message_transfer_agent_mta Alternatively, you can also use the SMTP port 2525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

port 587 will only apply to the smtp.sitecore.sparkpostelite.com machine; https is port 443.

Comment: Please elaborate, i.e. by citing and linking relevant source information.

Comment: There's no way to elaborate on this. I think it was the IANA in the mid 90s that allocated port 443 to HTTPS. They would have done 587 as well.  587 is an SMTP port. This is just how the internet works

Answer (score 1):

The Sitecore documentation is referring to outgoing traffic from your server.

You need to open port 587 for outgoing traffic only. You can leave this port closed for incoming traffic.